# GROUP BY takes forever

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this mysql statement in where you have a group by and an aggregate function, the avg one. The distance function here is simply the implementation of the cosine distance function.

The POI is 30k rows.

And immobilier_ad_blank is 500k.

```
SELECT 
c.id,
avg(dist(a.lat, a.lng, p.lat, p.lng)) as dist
FROM immobilier_ad_blank c
LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON c.adresse_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN POI AS p on p.discr = 'YellowPage'
WHERE p.keyword_id = '2' 
     AND p.lat IS NOT NULL 
     AND p.lng IS NOT NULL 
     AND p.lat != '' 
     AND p.lng != '' 
     AND p.lat != 'Latitude' 
     AND p.lng != 'Longitude'
     GROUP BY c.id;
```

The statement is whether stuck on `NULL`, `Opening table` and When I was on 5.5 `Copying Temp table.`

If I remove the `GROUP BY c.id` and the `avg` function, the statement executes in .5 sec.

Also, if executed with `INSERT INTO` statement, it takes around 1 min.

I also tried to manually execute the creation of the temporary table but it still won't move.

Finally, `p.lat,p.lng` and `a.lat,alng` have both clustered index.

For your information. The server has 2 GIG of ram. 
Any help on how to optimize this query.

This is the `Explain` as suggested:

```
[
{
    "id" : 1,
    "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
    "table" : "p",
    "partitions" : NULL,
    "type" : "ref",
    "possible_keys" : "IDX_EB1C5D5C115D4552,idxlat,idxlng",
    "key" : "IDX_EB1C5D5C115D4552",
    "key_len" : "5",
    "ref" : "const",
    "rows" : 228,
    "filtered" : 2.50,
    "Extra" : "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
    "table" : "c",
    "partitions" : NULL,
    "type" : "index",
    "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY,UNIQ_5E6BC6424B30D9C4,IDX_5E6BC6424DE7DC5C,IDX_5E6BC642999F7763,IDX_5E6BC642DB5A7180,IDX_5E6BC642498DA827,IDX_5E6BC64212469DE2,IDX_5E6BC642CC093B4A,IDX_5E6BC642900733ED,IDX_5E6BC642E1780C00,IDX_5E6BC6421BD9F3C1,idx1,idx2,idx3,idx4,idx5,idx6,idx0",
    "key" : "IDX_5E6BC6424DE7DC5C",
    "key_len" : "4",
    "ref" : NULL,
    "rows" : 560280,
    "filtered" : 100.00,
    "Extra" : "Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
    "table" : "a",
    "partitions" : NULL,
    "type" : "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY",
    "key" : "PRIMARY",
    "key_len" : "4",
    "ref" : "mganalyst.c.adresse_id",
    "rows" : 1,
    "filtered" : 100.00,
    "Extra" : NULL
}
]
```

I personally strongly think its related to the temporary table creation. How do you explain that `insert into` takes 1 min when the regular select take up to >2 hours.

Comment: Why the inner join POI don't have connection to your driving table Immobilier_Ad_Blank?

Comment: How come `lnt`,  `lng` store GPS coordinates as well as string (e.g. "Latitude")? Doesn't make sense. Also, do you mean `p.keyword_id = 2` ? Last, `AVG() + GROUP BY` is very resource consuming.

Comment: because theres no real connection, POI is for points of interests. I want them all. I simply want to find the distance between POIs and locations from the address table. And the Latitude and lng was coming form an excel file where the first row was the headers and I was too lazy to remove it so I chose both columns to be varchar... However, the query still executes fast without group by and avg, I dont think its the problem.

Comment: You CROSS join 500k rows times the number of rows returned by the WHERE-condition on POI, this might take some time.

Comment: ya I am indeed cross joining which in mysql CROSS = INNER = JOIN. I thought it could be related to some config/optimization in mysql `my.cnf`

Comment: Cross does not equal inner.

Comment: `In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html. But this is not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you where it is going wrong, but I agree that it seems abnormally slow, and it looks like it shouldn't be.  I can give you 3 places to look along with the how.

1. Make sure it isn't the function.  Replace the `avg(dist(...))` function with just `avg(a.lat)` and rerun the query.  See if there is a significant difference.  If there is, look to optimize the `dist(...)` function.
2. See if the problem is in one of the Joins.  Change the select to simply `SELECT count(1) cnt ...`, remove the `GROUP BY` and execute.  If it is still slow, remove each of the joins in turn executing to see which join might be causing the slow-down.  If the query speeds up substantially after removing one of the joins, look to see which indexes it is using to join the two tables.  If it isn't, put one in.
3. Shot in the dark:  Run 'optimize table xxx' on all three tables and see if that doesn't help.

Hopefully one of these suggestions helps.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was related to the `join on poi`  even though I added a related index. So after reflecting on my existence, I decided to sub separate this query per month. Sad hack, but at least, it works in a more acceptable fashion.